# Fixing vulnerability of maven-core

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am receiving critical vulnerability on maven-core package https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-26291. Need to upgrade maven-core to 3.8.1+.

[image]

Here ${spring.version} is 2.5.5.

From dependency tree found that spring-boot-maven-plugin(2.5.5)  -> maven-common-artifact-filters(3.2.0 latest version) -> maven-core(3.1.1)

So already we have maven-common-artifact-filters(3.2.0 latest version) which uses maven-core(3.1.1). SO how can we solve this? Whether we need to wait for any further release maven-common-artifact-filters which uses maven-core to 3.8.4? Please share your thoughts.

EDIT:
[image]

**EDIT**

We are using our internal repository manager to govern our repos, so then this vulnerability wont have impact right? we can suppress this?

**Settings.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://url/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://url/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://url/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
```

Comment: The issue is accessing repositories within pom's given via http only and **not** via https ...the solution is described https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html This means you have to upgrade your Maven installation (using more recent version like Maven 3.8.4) and change the configuration in `settings.xml` file... also it would be a good idea to upgrade spring boot version to most recent one (2.6.6) instead. And furthermore why defining a version for the maven-compiler-plugin (2.3.2 which is ancient)... and of course do not use Maven Plugins a dependencies it's wrong!

Comment: @khmarbaise We are using our own repository management, then it wont impact right? In the vulnerability statement it has statement lime that.

Comment: The first thing is how your `settings.xml` configuration looks like ...apart from upgrading to more recent versions of plugins/tools...

Comment: @khmarbaise Attached a sample from settngs.xml

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as a dependency in maven?

It's a plugin and, as such, it is used only during the building process - to prepare the artifact. The dependency itself is not a part of the artifact (at least usually, that's why I've asked why are you actually using it like that).

Usually this plugin is used like this (as a part of a `build` section):

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>the-app</artifactId>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

See [documentation of the plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle)

If it's not a dependency but a plugin, then there is no vulnerability to your application, at least the tools that have discovered the vulnerability probably analyze only the jars that are part of the final artifact...

Comment: Yes, plugin is something used by the build tool itself (maven in this case). Dependency is something that is required by the application to run (like a DLL, library, etc). So remove this plugin from the dependencies list and use the plugin in the build section. Then it won't be "under the radar" of the vulnerability analysis tool, because they usually analyze "dependencies" and not the build itself.

Comment: Edited my post . Build section also has spring-boot-maven-plugin. Is that enough?

Comment: Basically yes  try to remove this plugin from the dependencies and keep using it in the 'build' section. Then run the build, it should pass I believe. Then rerun your vulnarabilities detection tool. If all goes well, it will stop complaining :)

Comment: Remove the plugin from dependency it's simply wrong...apart from upgrading your Maven version and Spring Boot version...

Answer (score 0):

> We are using our internal repository manager to govern our repos, so then this vulnerability wont have impact right? we can suppress this?

That is the wrong solution.

You are missing the point.  The cause of the report is that your POM file is incorrect.  You have an incorrect **code** dependency on a Maven plugin that is used at **build** time.  The dependency should be removed from the POM file, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919577/139985.

When you fix the POM file (alleged) vulnerability should just go away.  The reported vulnerability is probably due to the checker *thinking* that your application uses the plugin and its dependencies ... including the vulnerable Maven component ... because you incorrectly told it that in the POM file.

The correct solution is to fix the POM file.  Get rid of the bogus dependency.

Comment: By removing that whether there will be any impact in the application?

Comment: No.  There shouldn't be.  Or if there is, you will discover it very quickly.  Just try it and see.   (Or if you don't believe us, dig into your application code-base to figure out exactly why it needs that vulnerable dependency at runtime.  And research the vulnerability to understand what it is really about.)